# Detecting audio from pc through browser

Tags: javascript, html, audio, browser, web

Is there any way for me to detect the audio that is currently playing on a PC through a webpage? The idea is to make a visualizer that visualizes your music that is playing or whatever you are listening to.

Comment: No, and it's a good thing your javascript code can't detect that and use ajax to send the results back to the server without the user noticing.

Comment: No. You can do that with audio that you embed in the page, but you can't reach out to the rest of the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this with JavaScript.